# Using config from PuPHPet for prod Server

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, puppet, ubuntu-14.04, puphpet

I built a testing Server with PuPHPet and Vagrant running Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a server with root acces running Ubuntu 14.04

My goal is to install all the software that I have on my Vagrant Box on my live server.
Therefore I've installed puppetmaster and puppet with "apt-get" and configured them to use the host "puppet" which I added in the host file of the live Server.

Then I copied everything from my Vagrant Box puphpet/puppet Folder to my server /etc/puppet/manifests.
I installed "augeas-tools and libaugeas-dev" with apt-get and run "/usr/bin/gem install haml hiera facter json ruby-augeas"

After that I tried to load the puppet manifest with "puppet agent --test" which kind of worked but produced this error: "Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Could not match |$key, at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/hhvm.pp:63 on node puppet"
So obviously it doesn't work that easy. Unfortunately I haven't found a tutorial or something on Stackoverflow to help me.

The Question is: How can I use the PuPHPet stuff on my live server to get it up and running, or what do I have to change? (Yes I know, I shouldn't use X-Debug, but besides that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuPHPet depends on the Puppet future parser for a few tools. The error you're seeing is the foreach that is available only in that parser.

Currently the easiest way to provision an existing server with a PuPHPet config is to use this plugin: https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers

Comment: So the propper way would be to have a Vagrant Box all normal and an additional managed Server Provisioner.

First i should bring up the Vagrant normal and if I'm ready to push it to the server, I should bring it up with the Managed Server provisioner and run the provisioning from Vagrant (that will then call the PuPHPet provisioning). Right?

Comment: @user2989952 vagrant-managed-servers does not handle the lifecycle of your server - it simply connects via SSH to the server and runs everything as it normally would.

Comment: Allright but that means it will run Puppet affter it connected to the server with ssh right? So basicaly it runs the Puppet scripts on the server but with all the Vagrant variables (meaning it's telling the Server to be in dev mode). Right?